# VS Code Keeps producing debug.log

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code suddenly started to produce a file called `debug.log` littering everywhere in my project directory. An example content is:

```
[0922/113308.083:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[0922/113308.120:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[0922/113345.228:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[0922/113345.241:ERROR:registration_protocol_win.cc(103)] CreateFile: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
```

What is causing this? How do I turn this off?

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with vs code 1.49.1, based on this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105191#issuecomment-695901095 there should be a fix later this week

Comment: What fixed this for me was only opening one instance of vs code.

Comment: Strange enough I came to this while looking for problems with chromium. This file is generated by CEF (chromium embedded framework) which seems to be used by Visual Studio code to render web pages.

Comment: I don't know what is causing this but open new terminal after killing all terminals work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linked to by @rahicks, this was a known issue. It has since been [fixed in release 1.49.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105191#issuecomment-698662938) and the bug closed.

Comment: That did fix it for me back then but now the problem has come back after updating to *v1.50* and *v1.50.1*  It's so annoying, every single directory in my projects gets a debug.log file in it with that error.

Comment: @RcoderNY Same issue and I have version 1.50

Comment: @giorgim Yeah I'm up to v1.51.1 and I still have the same problem.  I've tried a lot of different things to fix it but I still can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: @RcoderNY maybe we should open another issue on their repo

Comment: Still have the same issue with open folder with `code .` in terminal

Comment: Just started happening for me after updating to `1.78`